# Быстрый подсчёт количества делителей числа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа, факторизация

Никак не могу справиться с задачей, заданной в ВУЗе - пишет, что превышен лимит времени.
Я вообще не понимаю как тут её решить. Вот сама задача:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int f(int n)
{
   int i, c=0;
   for (i=1; i<=sqrt(n); i++)
   {
      if (n%i==0) c++;
   }
   if (sqrt(n)==int(sqrt(n))) 
      return 2*c-1;
   return 2*c; 
}

int main()
{
   int i,m,n,s=0;
   cin>>n>>m;
   for (i=2;i<=n;i++)
   {
      if (f(i)==m)
         s++;
   }
   cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох, побьют меня сейчас за неспортивное поведение... :( Но задачка интересная, хотелось бы узнать - все же нет ли какого-то способа побыстрее, чем перебор...

У меня - просто разложение на простые множители и произведение увеличенных на 1 степеней.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int primes[] = {
    2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
    61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 
    131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 
    197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 
    271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
    353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 
    433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 
    509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 
    601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 
    677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 
    769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 
    859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 
    953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 
    1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 
    1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 
    1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 
    1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 
    1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 
    1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 
    1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 
    1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 
    1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 
    1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 
    1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 
    1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 
    2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 
    2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 
    2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237};

unsigned CountOf(unsigned n, unsigned M)
{
    unsigned count = 1;
    if (n > 1)
    {
        for(unsigned q = 0, t = primes[0];
            t*t <= n && q < sizeof(primes)/sizeof(primes[0]);
            t = primes[++q])
        {
            if (n % t == 0)
            {
                unsigned d;
                for (d=0; !(n%t); ++d) n/=t;
                count *= d+1;
                if (count > M) return 0;
            }
        }
        if (n > 1) count *= 2;
        return count == M;
    }
    else return 0;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned N, M, count = 0;
    cin >> N >> M;

    for(unsigned i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
        count += CountOf(i,M);

    cout << count << endl;
}
```

**Update**
Немного ускорил - не считаем все корни, если уже перевалили нужное число.

Comment: Ооо, спасибо огромной, сайт принял программу, сейчас мне осталось разобраться в коде и до конца понять что тут да как. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Давайте научимся за линейное время находить все простые числа, заодно составим табличку для факторизации числа за кол-во чисел в факторизации, таким образом мы получим решение за O(N * const)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int n, m;
const int N = 5e6 + 3;
int lp[N + 1];
vector<int> pr;
void gen_primes() {
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (lp[i] == 0) {
            lp[i] = i;
            pr.push_back(i);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)pr.size() && pr[j] <= lp[i] && i * pr[j] <= N; ++j)
            lp[i * pr[j]] = pr[j];
    }
}
int count(int a) {
    int ans = 1, last_prime = lp[a], cur = 0;
    while (a > 1) {
        if (lp[a] != last_prime) {
            ans *= (cur + 1);
            cur = 0;
            last_prime = lp[a];
        }
        cur++;
        a /= lp[a];
        if (lp[a] == 1) break;
    }
    return ans * (cur + 1);
}

int32_t main() {
    pr.reserve(350000);
    gen_primes();
    cin >> n >> m;
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        ans += (count(i) == m);
    cout << ans;
}
```

[image: Спойлер - зашло]

Comment: Ускоряю генерацию простых чисел в два раза, а поиск множителей логарифмически.  Бесплатно, без регистрации и смс. ПС. Код с комментариями намного полезнее, чем без.

Comment: Предложенный вами алгоритм работает явно дольше, чем предложенный мной.

Comment: Я ещё ничего не предлагал 

Comment: Отличное решение!

Comment: Функция `count`, кажется, имеет сложность хуже чем `O(n)`. Там что-то вроде `O(nlog*(n))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool f(int n, int m) {
   bool res = false;
   int c = 0;
   for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
       if (n % i == 0) 
           c++;
       if (c == m) {
           break;
           res = true;           
       }
   }
}
```

И это в main

```
int main()
{
   int m, n, s = 0;
   cin >> n >> m;
   for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
   {
      if (f(i))
         s++;
   }
   cout << s << endl;
}
```

UPD: Я бы посоветовал вам не объявлять переменные для цикла for вне самого цикла, если уж не используете значение i после его завершения. А так же делайте отступы между арифм. операциями и всем остальным

Comment: Хм..., нужно сосчитать количество чисел от 1 до n включительно у которых количество делителей равно m. Как я понял, у вас в функции если количество делителей у числа больше чем m то он выводит false и всё. Но если количество делителей у числа != m то он должен тоже вывести false, даже проверяя работу программы числами из примера он уже выводит неправильно. А за совет про i вне цикла и отступы спасибо, буду использовать.

Comment: Уже исправил. На счёт i, все переменные которые работают только в цикле, лучше и объявлять внутри цикла, это упрощает отладку программы, да и удобство. А с отступами это чисто для читабельности. Хороший код принято писать не "слипшимся"

Answer (score 0):

[Решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1056541/416121) с линейным решетом и почти линейным разложением трудно превзойти по скорости. Зато эту задачу можно решить значительно проще. Решение укладывается в ограничения по памяти и скорости с запасом, не содержит корней и даже деления!

Идея: заведём вектор с количеством делителей данного числа. Перебираем делители от единицы до `n`. Для делителя `i` увеличиваем счётчик в ячейках `i`, `2i`, `3i`, ... Считаем количество m-простых:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::vector<int> n_divs(n + 1, 0);

    int n_mprimes = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {
            ++n_divs[j];
        }
        if (n_divs[i] == m) {
            ++n_mprimes;
        }
    }
    std::cout << n_mprimes << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 martian-primes.cpp 
>
> $ time echo 5000000 12 | ./a.out 
> 429792
>
> real  0m0.476s
> user  0m0.468s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Это в два раза медленее чем лучшее решение, зато в десять раз проще.