# Оптимизация поиска простых

Tags: java, c#, алгоритм, c++11, простые-числа

Помогите оптимизировать код для поиска простых чисел от 10000 до 99999

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 10001; i <=90000; i+=2)
        {
            if (isSimple(i))
            {
                // внесение в массив и тд.
            }
        }
    }
    //метод который определяет простое число или нет
    private static bool isSimple(int N)
    {
        //чтоб убедится простое число или нет достаточно проверить не делитсья ли 
        //число на числа до его половины
        for (int i = 2; i <= (int)(N / 2); i++)
        {
            if (N % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "на числа до его половины" - до его корня

Comment: [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Решето_Эратосфена).

Comment: Не следует изменять первоначальный код вопроса, если это не исправление опечаток.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос уже много-много раз рассматривался на ruSO.
Например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796468/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/796484#796484) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567608/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB).

Раз у вас есть метка `c++11` - могу себе позволить привести [код на C++](https://ideone.com/7JYtjL):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

unsigned int primes[] = {
    2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 
    61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 
    131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 
    197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 
    271, 277, 281, 283, 293};

const unsigned int pCount = sizeof(primes)/sizeof(primes[0]);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(unsigned int n = 10001; n <= 90000; n+=2)
    {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(unsigned int i = 1; i < pCount && primes[i]*primes[i] <= n; ++i)
        {
            if (n%primes[i] == 0) { is_prime = false; break;}
        }
        if (is_prime) cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```